# I am typing in text from a book for NSDictionary and get an error from it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I typed in text from a book and
I get this error:  Passing argument of 1 of "initWithObjects:forKeys:count:" from incompatible pointer type

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: @"hello", @"there", @"persn" 
            forKeys: @"aa", @"bb", @"cc"
            count: 3 ];

NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey: @"bb"]);
```

Comment: What book names it's dictionary variables `dick1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, methods can't use var-args like that, they must always come at the end of the invocation.

In fact, the parameters to your message invocation are actually pointers to buffers of objects and keys.

Try this:

```
id objects[] = {@"hello", @"there", @"person"};
id keys[] = {@"aa", @"bb", @"cc"};

NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys count:3];

NSLog(@"%@", [dict1 objectForKey: @"bb"]);
```